# how to capture package at a specific port on any interface using tshark

Tags: packet-capture, tshark

I want to capture the package on a specific port on **any** interface of my machine.

I know how to capture the package on a specific port with a specific interface.
And the command is

> tshark -f "udp port 162" -i bond0

And if no interface is specified, TShark searches the list of interfaces, choosing the first non-loopback interface if there are any non-loopback interfaces.

But I want to capture the package **on all the interface** of my machine.
Could anyone help me on this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
tshark -f "udp port 162" -i any
```

works for me here on Linux(CentOS).

Comment: Note that the "any" device is available only on Linux (other OS's packet capture mechanisms require that you specify a specific interface).